# 15.04: System will not shutdown or restart

Tags: 15.04, shutdown, restart

When I shut down the system by command from the menu top right behind the gear or turn off, this process gets stuck. When I look into the terminal with [ESC], I see that a USB drive is not being unmounted.

When I restart or shut down the system by command **from the terminal**,

```
sudo shutdown -r [now]
sudo shutdown -P [now]
```

**it works without any problems**. What does the menu item other than the shutdown command?

---

output from mount:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=4022672k,nr_inodes=1005668,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=806868k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=23,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/conte/lw640 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/conte/lw500 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,stripe=4)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
cgmfs on /run/cgmanager/fs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=806868k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

The problemtic drive is /dev/sdb1

output from smartctl:

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-30-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               PI-239
Product:              USB 2.0 Drive
Revision:             1.08
User Capacity:        500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

The problem has only existed for a few days, I have changed in the meantime knowingly nothing to the system.

Comment: The difference is probably `sudo`. Can you add the output of `mount` to your question? (also mention which is the USB drive that is not being unmounted)

Comment: @kos do a smartctl on the usb drive too! ;-)

Comment: And what @Fabby said: if it never did that and started suddenly, then probably something is wrong with the USB drive

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I have in the fstab the entry 'x-gvfs-show' removed.

old:

```
UUID=e6e1e5b3-5395-4145-9504-54bb926aab76 /media/conte/lw500 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

new:

```
UUID=e6e1e5b3-5395-4145-9504-54bb926aab76 /media/conte/lw500 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Now both, the restart and shutdown works properly again.

Comment: Yes, this *is* an answer!  Keep this one here!  **;-)**